# Check if the last file in os.listdir()

Tags: python, django, listdir

I need to know if the file currently checked in the os.listdir is the last file. I need it in a condition I have. Here is the code:

```
# iterate through all files in directory
for filename in os.listdir(edgar_path):
    # open and read
    with open(edgar_path + filename, 'r') as file:
        # rearrange by date (column 3)
        tsv_file = sorted(list(csv.reader(file, delimiter='|')), key=lambda t: t[3])

        # get date today
        today = datetime.datetime.now()  
        # get start date and end date depending on the first and last row
        start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(tsv_file[0][3], "%Y-%m-%d")
        end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(tsv_file[len(tsv_file) - 1][3], "%Y-%m-%d")
        # check print
        logger.debug(start_date)
        logger.debug(end_date)
        # if within date range
        if start_date <= today <= end_date:
            logger.debug('pass condition 1')
        # if not within date range, but
        # the date today is greater than the end date 
        # and its the last file being checked so it still passes
        elif today >= end_date:
            logger.debug('pass condition 2')
        # add to delete files if both conditions are unmet
        else:
            files_to_delete.append(filename)
            logger.debug('no pass')
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "last file?" What is the ordering by: date, time last modified, size? I see some mention of timestamps, but without an ordering on the files there is no way to determine which is last, first, or anything in between.

Comment: @MichaelRuth, the file has been sorted. line 6 `sorted(list(csv.reader(file, delimiter='|')), key=lambda t: t[3])`. It's sorted by date

Comment: That line sorts only the content of the file, not the list of files itself.

Comment: @MichaelRuth, I downloaded the list of files from [python-edgar](https://pypi.org/project/python-edgar/). It already lists it by quarter, so it's fine. I just need to find the last of the downloaded quarters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can put the filenames in a list variable (`filenames` in the below code) and check if the `filename` is the last item in the `filenames` list by using the condition

```
filename == filenames[-1]
```

```
# iterate through all files in directory
filenames = os.listdir(edgar_path)
for filename in filenames:
    # open and read
    with open(edgar_path + filename, 'r') as file:
        # rearrange by date (column 3)
        tsv_file = sorted(list(csv.reader(file, delimiter='|')), key=lambda t: t[3])

        # get date today
        today = datetime.datetime.now()
        # get start date and end date depending on the first and last row
        start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(tsv_file[0][3], "%Y-%m-%d")
        end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(tsv_file[len(tsv_file) - 1][3], "%Y-%m-%d")
        # check print
        logger.debug(start_date)
        logger.debug(end_date)
        # if within date range
        if start_date <= today <= end_date:
            logger.debug('pass condition 1')
        # if not within date range, but
        # the date today is greater than the end date
        # and its the last file being checked so it still passes
        elif today >= end_date:
            logger.debug('pass condition 2')
        # add to delete files if both conditions are unmet
        else:
            files_to_delete.append(filename)
            logger.debug('no pass')
    
    # check for last file here
    if filename == filenames[-1]:
        # Do something
```

Comment: yeah, this worked. thanks! I used `last_file = os.listdir(edgar_path)[-1]`

Comment: @ProsyArceno Yeah, that works too. `filename == filenames[-1]` might be more efficient performance-wise though since using `last_file = os.listdir(edgar_path)[-1]` would require you to call `os.listdir` function multiple times instead of once

Comment: got that. Will change it to filenames. Thanks!

Comment: can you help with this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69081067/12415287)? It was okay until I tried on the server.