# File arrangement different in Ubuntu server

Tags: python

I have a problem retrieving the last file from some files with these filenames:

On Windows localhost:

[image]

On Ubuntu server:

[image]

Its all arranged by year and by quarter. I need the last file for 1 of my scripts, and the way I access it is by doing:

```
filenames = os.listdir(edgar_path)
last_file = filenames[-1]
```

It works fine on my localhost on my Windows PC, but it's working unexpectedly on the Ubuntu server.

When I try to print the last file being retrieved, it's different on the server.

```
logger.debug('last_file')
logger.debug(last_file)
```

Windows localhost result:

[image]

Ubuntu Server result:

[image]

It's the same script, with the same files but for some reason, it's returning the wrong file in the servers script.

Any idea what might cause this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.listdir()` [returns a list in arbitrary order](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir), which doesn't guarantee that the last file is always going to be the same. If you want the list to be ordered on both platforms, you need to [sort it](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) yourself by calling `sort()` or `sorted()` on the list returned by `os.listdir()`.

A short example using your code:

```
filenames = os.listdir(edgar_path)
filenames.sort()
last_file = filenames[-1]
```